# Strange Way to Initialize std::string with C string

Tags: c++, c, string, cuda

while I was reading nVidia CUDA source code, I stumbled upon these two lines:

```
    std::string stdDevString;

    stdDevString = std::string(device_string);
```

Note that device_string is a char[1024]. The question is: Why construct an empty std::string, then construct it again with a C string as an argument? Why didn't they call `std::string stdDevString = std::string(device_string);` in just one line?

Is there a hidden string initialization behavior that this code tries to evade/use? Is to ensure that the C string inside stdDevString remains null terminated no matter what? Because as far as I know, initializing an std::string to a C string that's not null terminated will still exhibit problems.

Comment: Dunno, looks just as redundant to me as it does to you. In fact, it's probably initializing twice. But, then again, maybe the compiler is smart enough to optimize that away.

Comment: @Voulnet: my bet is C-style. In C you have to declare (without initializing) all the local variables you're about to use at the beginning of the block.

Comment: @aaz: Actually you gave to according to the C standard, unless it was updated or so. But some compilers go lax about that rule anyways.

Comment: @Voulnet:  You are correct about declaring at the beginning of a block for ISO C90, but incorrect about initialising; you can certainly initialise in the declaration. C99 on the other hand works like C++ in this respect, so it is not a matter of compilers being "lax".

Comment: @Clifford: Actually I know about initialization, I was more commenting about declaring, but it seems I didn't specify. Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why didn't they call `std::string stdDevString = std::string(device_string);` in just one line?

No good reason for what they did.  Given the `std::string::string(const char*)` constructor, you can simply use any of:

```
std::string stdDevString = device_string;
std::string stdDevString(device_string);
std::string stdDevString{device_string}; // C++11 { } syntax
```

The two-step default construction then assignment is just (bad) programmer style or oversight.  Sans optimisation, it does do a little unnecessary construction, but that's still pretty cheap.  It's likely removed by optimisation.  Not a biggie - I doubt if I'd bother to mention it in a code review unless it was in an extremely performance sensitive area, but it's definitely best to defer declaring variables until a useful initial value is available to construct them with, localising it all in one place: not only is it less error prone and cross-referenceable, but it minimises the scope of the variable simplifying the reasoning about its use.

> Is to ensure that the C string inside `stdDevString` remains null terminated no matter what?

No - it made no difference to that.  Since C++11 the internal buffer in `stdDevString` would be kept NUL terminated regardless of which constructor is used, while for C++03 isn't not necessarily terminated - see dedicated heading for C++03 details below - but there's no guarantees regardless of how construction / assignment is done.

> Because as far as I know, initializing an `std::string` to a C string that's not null terminated will still exhibit problems.

You're right - any of the construction options you've listed will only copy ASCIIZ text into the `std::string` - considering the first NUL (`'\0'`) the terminator.  If the char array isn't NUL-terminated there will be problems.

(That's a separate issue to whether the buffer inside the `std::string` is kept NUL terminated - discussed above).

Note that there's a separate `string(const char*, size_type)` constructor that ***can*** create strings with embedded NULs, and won't try to read further than told (Constructor (4) [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string))

### C++03 std::strings were not guaranteed NUL-terminated internally

Whichever way the `std::string` is constructed and initialised, ***before C++11*** the Standard did not require it to be NUL-terminated within the string's buffer.  `std::string` was best imagined as containing a bunch of potentially non-printable (loosely speaking, binary in the ftp/file I/O sense) characters starting at address `data()` and extending for `size()` characters.  So, if you had:

```
std::string x("help");
x[4];  // undefined behaviour: only [0]..[3] are safe
x.at(4); // will throw rather than return '\0'
x.data()[4]; // undefined behaviour, equivalent to x[4] above
x.c_str()[4]; // safely returns '\0', (perhaps because a NUL was always
              // at x[4], one was just added, or a new NUL-terminated
              // buffer was just prepared - in which case data() may
              // or may not start returning it too)
```

Note that the std::string API requires `c_str()` to return a pointer to a NUL-terminated value.  To do so, it can either:

- proactively keep an extra `NUL` on the end of the string buffer at all times (in which case `data[5]` *would happen* to be safe on that implementation, but the code could break if the implementation changed or the code was ported to another Standard library implementation etc.)
- reactively wait until `c_str()` is called, then:

  - **if** it has enough capacity at the current address (i.e. `data()`), append a `NUL` and return the same pointer value that `data()` would return
  - otherwise, allocate a new, larger buffer, copy the data over, `NUL` terminate it, and return a pointer to it (typically *but optionally* this buffer would replace the old buffer which would be deleted, such that calling `data()` immediately afterwards would return the same pointer returned by `c_str()`)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with more detail in the last paragraph, please?

Comment: @Voulnet: I've tried to explain better above... further queries welcome.

Comment: Okay, so you're saying that in the end, c_str() could contain unprintable characters that were copied from data() ?

Comment: @Voulnet: yes, it certainly will if the string was constructed with or modified to contain such characters.  `c_str()` may even have additional ASCII `NUL` characters before the one at offset `size() + 1`, but only if constructed using the `std::string(const char*, size)` constructor or added later using e.g. `+= '\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that it's equivalent of writing:

```
std::string stdDevString = std::string(device_string);
```

Or, even simpler:

```
std::string stdDevString = device_string;
```

Once the std::string has been created, it contains a private copy of the data in the C string.

Comment: I am aware of that, as provided in the question body itself, but that's the entire point: If it's just equivalent to that in the end, why split it into two strange lines with two constructors being called? Is there a certain behavior they're trying to evade here?

Comment: +1 This actually is the correct answer - there is no difference and we cannot know why the original coder chose one of the alternatives. High exposure to old C code is a guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is ignorant to dismiss this as poor coding. If we assume that this string was allocated at file scope or as a static variable, it could be *good* coding.

When programming C++ for embedded systems with non-volatile memory present, there are many reasons why you wish to avoid static initialization: the main reason is that it adds lots of overhead code in the beginning of the program, where all such variables much be initialized. If they are instances of classes, constructors will be called.

This will lead to a delay peak at the beginning of the program execution. You *don't* want this workload peak there, because there are much more important tasks to do when starting up the program, like setting up various hardware.

To avoid this, you typically enable an option in the compiler which removes such static initialization, and then write your code in such a manner that no static/global variables are initialized, but instead set them in runtime.

On such a system, the code posted by the OP is the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an artefact to me. Perhaps there was some other code in between, then it got removed, and someone was too lazy to join those two remaining lines into a single one.